# Coordinate and Coordinates tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

There are two tags for the same thing: [coordinate](/questions/tagged/coordinate) and [coordinates](/questions/tagged/coordinates). They should probably be synonyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you're right.  With nearly 1300 questions tagged [coordinates](/questions/tagged/coordinates) (plural) and about 100 questions tagged [coordinate](/questions/tagged/coordinate) (singular), there's little doubt that the plural should be the canonical name and the singular removed or synonymized (is that the word?).

Comment: [You are correct, sir](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synonymize)

Comment: [tag:coordinate] should just be killed. It's very rare that people actually refer to coordinates outside of the plural form, and typing in the singular form in the tag box will bring up the plural form of it, so it doesn't make sense to even keep the singular form around (since new tags can't be the singular or plural form of an existing tag now).

Comment: 'coordinate' singular might used sometimes as a verb 'coordinate the processes'.  Since it has no wiki summary, that will require scrutiny of the questions to ensure that 'coordinates' (which does have a wiki summary referring to 'groups of numbers to describe the position of an object').  But I tend to agree that burninating 'coordinate' is likely the correct solution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think that using _coordinate_ as verb is a much helpful tag.